# Populate People Picker from a SharePoint Person or Group Column

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, asp.net

I have a visual webpart with a people picker in it which does successfully save people chosen to a SharePoint person or group column on my Entry Form. On my custom Edit Form I just need to read the people back out of the same SharePoint person or group column into the People Picker so they can be edited. I'm attempting this in C#.

Answer (score 0):

```
SPFieldUserValueCollection userValueCollection = new SPFieldUserValueCollection(SPContext.Current.Web, SPContext.Current.Item["Field"] as string);
                        if (userValueCollection.Count > 0)
                        {
                            MypeopleEditor.CommaSeparatedAccounts = userValueCollection[0].User.LoginName;
                        }
```

I was able to find a solution. I hope this helps.